# How can I put a blue line in front of a quotation?

Tags: color, quotation

I want to put a blue line to the left of a quotation that has the exact size of the height of the quotation.
It should look like the following image.

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! By use of `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tcolorbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{enhanced,
                     boxrule=0pt,
                     frame hidden,
                     borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{blue!25!white},
                     colback=white,
                     sharp corners,
                     right=0pt, 
                     top=0pt, 
                     bottom=0pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1-2] 
\end{mybox}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```